# How to refresh Windows Cache

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables

Installing our application will add a new system environmental variable.  The version number will vary depending upon the kit installed. Say for example one kit has 10.0.0.1 means the other kit will have 10.0.0.2 and so on.

Consider I am installing the 2nd kit on top of 1st kit (which has the version 10.0.0.1), in the system environmental variable I could see the correct value of 10.0.0.2. Also if I navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment, I could see the environment variable is having correct version.

If I type echo %MYKITPATH% in command window also it is correctly giving as 'C:\Program Files(x86)\MYKIT\10.0.0.2'. However if I type %MYKITPATH% to navigate to the path, it is opening the path of older version 'C:\Program Files(x86)\MYKIT\10.0.0.1'.

I tried to do the following to refresh the ENV variable, still it didn't solve the problem.
Even if I try to get the enviroment variable, it points to the newer version. Only in the start window, if i try to navigate to the path using environmental variable, having the problem. If i open the run window (Windows+R), it is navigating correctly. From explorer, it is navigating correctly. It's just with the start window I am having the problem
This is not happening in all the machines. If it happens, the only way to work around is to reboot the machine.

So I guess refreshing environment variable is not the problem here, somehow windows is caching the old values somewhere. That's why explorer.exe works and problem is with only start window.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MYKITPATH", installedPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MYKITPATH", installedPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MYKITPATH", installedPath, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);


Variable name: MYKITPATH
Variable value: C:\Program Files(x86)\MYKIT\10.0.0.2
```

Comment: Are you saying that in a console window you type `echo %MYKITPATH%` and see the correct value but then in the same window you type `dir %MYKITPATH%` and you get a different value? I don't believe that is possible. Are you using two different console windows or processes? Or do you mean that the `PATH` value is not updated when `MYKITPATH` is changed?

Comment: In the same window if I type dir %MYKITPATH% it says, The system cannot find the path specified. But when I try to navigate to that path by opening start-> and type %mykitpath% in the start window, it navigates to old version.

Comment: From the run window or from the explorer, it is working correctly. Only from the start window, it is having the problem.

Comment: The run box in the Start window will refresh when you logout and then log back in (or restart the machine). Environment variables are passed to a process when the process is started. A process doesn't get updates of environment variables.

Comment: Try adding quotes, as there's an space on the path: `dir "%MYKITPATH%"`

Comment: dir "%igxlroot%" also pointing to the correct path. I think the windows is holding some cache and that's why it still points to old version and only a reboot is resolving that

Comment: @JonathanDodds Is there anyway to refresh the run box in start window without logout/reboot?

Comment: An *EXISTING* command prompt *CANNOT* see the update to a Windows variable (if that's what you're trying to do).  You *MUST* initiate a *NEW* command prompt, which should *ALWAYS* see the new, current value.  Regardless of how you started the prompt.  Q: For the "run box", Have you tried [wsreset](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-clear-cache-in-windows--10)?

Comment: @paulsm4: Actually the environment is inherited from the parent, so if you spawn a command prompt from a process that had an old copy of the environment, the new command prompt will also use that old data.

Comment: There is no problem with the command prompt. If i spawn the command box from run or through start window, in any case it points to the correct path (Only If I directly type it in the start window, I have the problem). Yes, I ran wsreset too. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` to all top-level windows with lParam of `"Environment"`.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange

Note that the "cache" is not Windows-wide, it is the process environment block in each independent running process, and each process must include logic to handle `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` (which is non-trivial, most applications won't do so, but the Windows shell which handles the start menu textbox, does)

Although since you say Windows Explorer sees the new value, I suspect this broadcast has already been done for you by .NET

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work out too. SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(ENVIRONMENT), SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, MSG_TIMEOUT, out RESULT);

Comment: @StackUser: That call has several problems.  What `CharSet` did you use for the declaration of `SendMessageTimeout` ?

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

Comment: Well `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi` is incompatible with `CharSet.Auto` (and on top of that, it causes a memory leak).  Change that parameter from `IntPtr` to `string`, then p/invoke will match the charset to the version it calls `GetProcAddress` for -- the memory doesn't need to outlive the function call, so there is no need for explicit allocation.

Comment: it doesn't allow to change to string. getting compiler error saying cannot convert from system.intptr to string

Comment: @StackUser: After you make the change, there would be no IntPtr needing to be converted.  Just `"Environment"`

Comment: Changed to string and called the sendmessagetimeout. Still it navigates to old version